# Passing multiple query parameters to CategoryPageController

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a category whereby I have several other filter criterias. So what is the proper syntax to filter it on the basis of fields `f1` and `f2` :

```
/mystorefront/c/{myCategory}/?q=:-(-(f1:black) OR -(f2:large))
```

Is it the correct *URL* for filtering, or should the keyword `OR` not used here?Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use `OR` operator in `SOLR` front query, You should use something like :

```
/mystorefront/c/{myCategory}/?q=:pertinence:f1:black:f2:large
```

*pertinence* : is the default sort rule.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your suggestion.Is the functionality for this provided OOB by Hybris or you have to make some other changes apart from creating category and indexing f1 and f2 as facets

Comment: ,should f 1 and f2 be be the field values or the attribute values.eg if we have a string attribute like color but it is in Solr as color_string so will we query it as color or color_string?Is the syntax same for multi valued attributes and single string attributes?

Comment: `f1` and `f2`, should be the attribute name without the `_string` or `_text`.  `black` and `large` should be the values of your attribut of the element that you look for.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your reply.I initially thought the Solr way and Hybris way would be same and that the Hybris syntax for multivalued and for single attributes would be different with double quotes.Now from what I gather,same syntax for both and no quotes.

Comment: ,thanks a lot but it worked like this:           
     /mystorefront/c/{myCategory}/?q=:fq:f1:black:f2:large